# Adding an Active Directory user using a specific DC in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a requirement to test each Domain Controller in a very large AD schema to assure that user creates are successful. I am building a script to do this in PowerShell so I can repeat the test as necessary. The script will create a user in each AD, and then check the public properties of the user on each DC to assure the creation was successful.

The input to this script will be a text file of DC names.

The Active Directory Cmdlets has New-ADUser, which creates a new AD user. It does not, however, allow the developer to specify a specific Domain Controller.

Is there a way to create an AD user using a specific Domain Controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all cmdlets in the ActiveDirectory module have the ability to target a specific DC.

For `New-ADUser` use the `-Server` parameter.  See the [MDSN documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617253.aspx)

Comment: I honestly can't believe I missed that. Read that page 544 times. Thanks!